# asp.net c# linq generate list from model base on id from another list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

My application is .net Core MVC. I have two classes

```
 public class Product
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Buyer { get; set; }
        public int? ProductId  { get; set; }

        public ProductType ProductType { get; set; }
    }

public class ProductType
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Product> Product { get; set; }
    }
```

I am trying to generate a list of product name using the following:

```
List<ProductType> productnames;
var products = _context.Product().Where(x => x.Buyer == "Test" && x.ProductId != null).ToList();
foreach (var item in products)
{
productnames = _context.ProductType.Where(c => c.ProductId == item.ProductId).ToList(); 
}
```

Although I have 3 items in the list (products), I get just one item in productnames list.

> Note: I can't use Include because I am using another Core Web API to retrieve the data and
>   can't use oData to return IQueryable object.  So as a workaround I am
>   using Sqlite for the client application, while the API is using MS
>   Sql.

Comment: @StephenMuecke, thank you. It worked great.

Comment: So check his answer with the green tick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only get one item (which will be the value from the last iteration) because you keep overwriting the value of `productnames` in each iteration.

You would need to add the result to the list. Assuming your `.Where(c => c.ProductId == item.ProductId)` returns only one record, then you could use `.Single()`, for example

```
foreach (var item in products)
{
    productnames.Add(_context.ProductType.Single(c => c.ProductId == item.ProductId)); 
}
```

However you can simplify this by using a `.Contains()` statement

```
// Select just the ProductId
var products = _context.Product
    .Where(x => x.Buyer == "Test" && x.ProductId != null)
    .Select(x => x.ProductId);
List<ProductType> productnames = _context.ProductType
    .Where(x => products.Contains(x.ProductId)).ToList();
```